# What is the simplest and most reliable way to send a command-line command in python, and print the stdout and stderr?

Tags: python, linux, websocket, raspberry-pi

To elaborate on what I'm doing:

I want to create a web-based CLI for my Raspberry Pi. I want to take a websocket and connect it to this Raspberry Pi script, so that the text I type into the webpage will get entered directly into the CLI on the raspberry pi, and the response will return to me on the webpage.

My first goal is creating the python script that can properly send a user-inputted command to the CLI and return all responses in the CLI back.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the return value you can use [os.system](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.system), but then you won't get the output of stdout and stderr. So you probably have to use the [subprocess](http://xahlee.info/perl-python/system_calls.html) module, which requires you to split the input text into command and parameters first.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module in the standard library. This will allow you to interact with the CLI from a python script.

Answer (score 0):

The `subprocess` module will do this for you but has a few quirks. You can pass in file objects to the various calls to bind to `stderr` and `stdout`, but they have to be real file objects. `StringIO` doesn't cut it.

The below uses `check_output()` as it grabs `stdout` for us and saves us opening a file. I'm sure there's fancier way of doing this.

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError


def shell(command):
    stdout = None

    with TemporaryFile('rw') as fh:
        try:
            stdout = check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=fh)

        except CalledProcessError:
            pass

        # Rewind the file handle to read from the beginning
        fh.seek(0)
        stderr = fh.read()

    return stdout, stderr


print shell("echo hello")[0]
    # hello
print shell("not_a_shell_command")[1]
    # /bin/sh: 1: not_a_shell_command: not found
```

As one of the other posters mentions, you should really cleanse your input to prevent security exploits (and drop the `shell=true`). To be honest though, your project sounds like you are purposefully building a remote execution exploit for yourself, so it probably doesn't matter.